# Downloading old macOS from a newer Mac to install on an external hard drive

Tags: macos, install

I have an older MacBook Pro that had some HDD issues.  Now the Mac doesn't have a working OS and I need to install MacOS.  The newest version that it can use is Mac OS Mountain Lion.  So I borrowed a friends new MacBook, logged into the Mac App Store with my Apple ID, and the bought it.

But now I can't download it because when I click download, it says this version of MacOS is not compatiable with the newer MacBook.

Which is fine, but I'm not trying to install it on the new Mac, I just want to copy the install over to an external hard drive so that I can then use it to install macOS on the older mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you purchased the OS from Apple, contact Apple!

Comment: Can you download it from the "Purchased" tab? Or are you already trying it there?

Answer (score 2):

What model (and year) is the older mac?

Hold down cmd-opt-r on restart on your new Mac. This will boot into MacOS Internet Recovery where you will be able to install the OS that shipped on the new Mac (if its compatible - thats why I need the model and year). From there you may be able to install or upgrade your MacOS version.

Comment: From everymac.com: Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.5 13" Mid-2012 Specs
Identifiers: Mid-2012 13" - MD101LL/A* - MacBookPro9,2 - A1278 - 2554*

Comment: Ok so it isnt that old, which means it qualifies for even the latest MacOS software. If you want you can set up the old mac with everything from the new Mac via Target disk mode. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25318?locale=en_US

Comment: Internet recovery sure is neat, but advising it doesn't answer the question. In my case, the mac in question is a Mini from mid 2011. Internet recovery installs OS X 10.7, which is so old that its SSL implementation leaves pretty much everything on the web unavailable or broken, App Store included. I just want to download 10.13.